# If $f(z)$ is entire function such that $|f(z)f'(z)| \leq 1$ then $f(z)$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

If $f(z)$ is entire function such that $|f(z)f'(z)| \leq 1$ then $f(z)$ is constant.

Choose $g(z) = \frac {(f(z))^2}{2}$, $g'(z) = f(z)f'(z) \implies |g'(z)| \leq 1$(given condition)

So $g'(z)$ is analytic and bounded. By lioville theorem we have $g'(z) = A$ where A is a constant

$f(z)f'(z) = A$

$f(z) df(z) = A dz$

Integrating we get

$f(z) = \sqrt{Az+b}$ where A,b are constants

But the question asks $f(z)$ to be proved as constant. But i got different. Pls have a look at where i made mistake. It looks correct to me

Comment: $\mathrm df(z)$??

Comment: I think that would mean the $\int \mathrm{d} f(z)$ or equivalently the $\int \mathrm{d}z \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z}$ operator.

Comment: $\sqrt{Az}$ is entire only if $A = 0$.

Comment: @JalexStark how can we say A = 0 for $\sqrt {Az}$ be entire? I recently started complex analysis. Pls elaborate

Comment: What's your definition of entire?

Comment: @JalexStark entire means it is analytic through out in complex plane. Analytic at a point means all differentiable in neighbourhood of a point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You proved correctly that $g(z)=Az+B$ for some numbers $A$ and $B$. In other words,$$f^2(z)=2Az+2B.$$Therefore, $\lim_{z\to\infty}\left|\frac{f^2(z)}{z^2}\right|=0$. But$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\left|\frac{f^2(z)}{z^2}\right|=0\iff\lim_{z\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(z)}z\right|^2=0\iff\lim_{z\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(z)}z\right|=0.$$So, $f$ is a polynomial function and its degree is $1$, at most. But, since its square doesn't have degree $2$, $f$ is, in fact, a constant polynomial.

Comment: thank you. Got it

Comment: The part where $f$ is polynomial seems to be the part that anirudh is unable to prove.

Comment: @JalexStark If he has a problem with that, I will explain him why it is true.

Comment: thank you i understood the way you have neatly explained

Comment: But when i googled i saw a theorem - an entire function has no zeros. Is this true? Entire function = differentiable function through out in complex plane. How can it has no zeroes? For ex., polynomial function has zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

If $2g(z)=f^2(z)$, then every zero of $g$ is a zero of $f$.

Since $g'(z)=f(z)f'(z)$, every zero of $f$ is a zero of $g'$.

Therefore, every zero of $g$ is a double zero, at least.

Now $g(z)=Az+B$ has a simple zero if $A\ne0$.

Therefore, $A=0$ and $f$ is constant.